# How do I find the area of the intersection of the two circles generated by the strophoid of a circle?

Tags: geometry, area

As a refresher, the definition of the strophoid of a curve is given as thus:

> Take some curve $C$ with two points, $O$ (the origin) and $A$ (the pole). Then, construct a line $L$ that passes through $O$ and some point $C$ at $K$. Now construct a circle centered at $K$ that passes through $A$. Call the two points that this circle intersects with $L$ as $P_1$ and $P_2$. The strophoid of a curve is the set of all $P_1$ and $P_2$ for all $K$ on $C$.

In particular, I now want to discuss the strophoid of the unit circle where $O$ and $A$ are both points on the circle's circumference. Say that the point $O$ is given by $\bigr(\cos{(t_1)},\sin{(t_1)}\bigl)$ and $A$ by $\bigr(\cos{(t_2)},\sin{(t_2)}\bigl)$, with $-\pi\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq\pi$. Then the strophoid of the unit circle with these two point will be, itself, a pair of circles. Namely, it will be a pair of circles whose origins lie on the intersection of the curves $r=1$ and $\theta=\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}$ - that is, on the points $(\pm\cos{(\frac{t_1+t_2}{2})},\pm\sin{\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}})$. As an illustrative example, I have a diagram of the case where $O=(1,0)$ and $A=(0,1)$. Notice how the strophoid circles are centered on the points $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

[image: The unit circle, colored red, overlayed with two other circles, colored black, one small and one large, but both with origins on the line y=x.]

What is the area of the intersection of these circles? We can find the area of the individual circles fairly easily - in the example above, we know that $(0,1)$ is on the circumference and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ is our origin, so we can see that the area of this circle is $(2-\sqrt{2})\pi$. By a similar argument, we can find that the area of the larger circle is $(2+\sqrt{2})\pi$. However, when it comes to finding the area of the intersection, I'm blanking. I feel like *maybe* you could do this by shifting everything up and to the right by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ units and then doing something with a double integral in polar coordinates, but nothing is coming to me at the moment. Also bear in mind that I am requesting the general form for arbitrary $t_1$ and $t_2$ (if it can be found). Thank you!

Comment: Do you already know the general formula for the strophoid circles themselves? That is, if you had a formula that said "If two circles of radius $r_1, r_2$ are at distance $x$ from each other, then the area of their intersection is _____" do you know enough to find $r_1, r_2, x$ in terms of $t_1, t_2$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes. Due to the way the strophoid is generated, the circles will always intersect the unit circle at $A$. With a known origin and a point on the circumference, the radius can be found.

Comment: Specifically, the radius will be $\sqrt{(\cos{(t_2)}-\cos({\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}}))^2+(\sin{(t_2)}-\sin{(\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}}))^2}$

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I misunderstood your question - I do not know the general formula offhand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the diagram, assuming the radii of the circles and their intersection points are known,

[image]

$$
L^2=(x_a-x_b)^2+(y_a-y_b)^2
$$
From the isosceles triangle of the big circle,
$$
L^2= 2r_2^2 - 2r_2^2\cos(\theta_2)\\
\cos(\theta_2)=1-\frac{L^2}{2r_2^2}\\
\theta_2=\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_2^2})
$$
The height of the triangle in the big circle is $h = r_2\cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2})$, so the area of the triangle is
$$
A_2=\frac{1}{2}r_2L\cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2})\\
\cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2})=\sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_2^2}}\\
A_2=\frac{1}{2}r_2L\sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_2^2}}
$$
The area of the wedge of the pie in the big circle subtended by the angle $\theta_2$ is
$$
\int_0^{\theta_2}\int_0^{r_2} rdrd\theta=\frac{1}{2}r_2^2\theta_2
$$
Thus the area in the big circle above the line segment $L$ is,
$$
\frac{1}{2}r_2^2\theta_2-A_2=\frac{1}{2}r_2^2\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_2^2})-\frac{1}{2}r_2L\sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_2^2}}
$$
Similarly we find for the area above the line segment $L$ in the smaller circle
$$
\frac{1}{2}r_1^2\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_1^2})-\frac{1}{2}r_1L\sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_1^2}}
$$
The region of over lap of the two circles is thus
$$
\frac{1}{2}r_1^2\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_1^2})+\frac{1}{2}r_2^2\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{L^2}{2r_2^2})-\frac{L}{2}\left [r_1\sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_1^2}}+r_2\sqrt{1-\frac{L^2}{4r_2^2}}\right]
$$